# Akka HTTP Java client example to POST JSON msg

Tags: java, json, http-post, akka-http

How do I write a Java HTTP client using Akka HTTP, to POST a JSON message using a marshaller to convert a POJO to JSON. All I can find are examples like this:

```
HttpRequest req =
    HttpRequest.POST("/user")
        .withEntity(HttpEntities.create(
            ContentTypes.APPLICATION_JSON,
            "{\"some\": json}"
        ));
```

which hard-code the JSON instead of using a marshaller.

Comment: You can try using a spray-json.
https://github.com/spray/spray-json

Comment: @ShankarShastri that doesn't address my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use any json marshaller in place of hardcoded string and it should works. Below I put example with jackson marshaller.

```
class RequestProducer {
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public RequestProducer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
       this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    HttpRequest post(SomePojo somePojo) {
        return HttpRequest.POST("/user")
            .withEntity(HttpEntities.create(
              ContentTypes.APPLICATION_JSON,
              objMapper.writeValueAsString(somePojo)));        
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I figured that out, but was wondering if there was a way to use a marshaller given the framework uses them pretty much everywhere else. Will accept this answer unless a better one turns up...